# How to store formatting settings with an IOStream?

Tags: c++, iostream, istream, ostream

When creating formatted output for a user defined type it is often desirable to define custom formatting flags. For example, it would be nice if a custom string class could optionally add quotes around the string:

```
String str("example");
std::cout << str << ' ' << squotes << str << << ' ' << dquotes << str << '\n';
```

should produce

```
example 'example' "example"
```

It is easy enough to create *manipulators* for changing the formatting flags themselves:

```
std::ostream& squotes(std::ostream& out) {
    // what magic goes here?
    return out;
}
std::ostream& dquotes(std::ostream& out) {
    // similar magic as above
    return out;
}
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, String const& str) {
    char quote = ????;
    return quote? out << quote << str.c_str() << quote: str.c_str();
}
```

... but how can the manipulators store which quotes should be used with the stream and later have the output operator retrieve the value?

Comment: When I first read the question I was confused because I knew you already knew the answer. LOL :)

Comment: @0x499602D2: the FAQ encourages asking questions and answering them directly (it is even supported by the interface) and I thought this would be question whose answer would be useful to others.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The streams classes were designed to be extensible, including the ability to store additional information: the stream objects (actually the common base class `std::ios_base`) provide a couple of functions managing data associated with a stream:

1. `iword()` which takes an `int` as key and yields an `int&` which starts out as `0`.
2. `pword()` which takes an `int` as key and yields a `void*&` which starts out as `0`.
3. `xalloc()` a `static` function which yields a different `int` on each call to "allocate" a unique key (they keys can't be released).
4. `register_callback()` to register a function which is called when a stream is destroyed, `copyfmt()` is called, or a new `std::locale` is `imbue()`d.

For storing simple formatting information as in the `String` example it is sufficient to allocate an `int` and store a suitable value in an `iword()`:

```
int stringFormatIndex() {
    static int rc = std::ios_base::xalloc();
    return rc;
}
std::ostream& squote(std::ostream& out) {
    out.iword(stringFormatIndex()) = '\'';
    return out;
}
std::ostream& dquote(std::ostream& out) {
    out.iword(stringFormatIndex()) = '"';
    return out;
}
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, String const& str) {
    char quote(out.iword(stringFormatIndex()));
    return quote? out << quote << str.c_str() << quote: out << str.c_str();
}
```

The implementation uses the `stringFormatIndex()` function to make sure that exactly one index is allocate as `rc` is initialized the first time the function is called. Since `iword()` returns `0` when there is no value, yet, set for a stream, this value is used for the default formatting (in this case to use no quotes). If a quote should be used the `char` value of the quote is simply stored in the `iword()`.

Using `iword()` is rather straight forward because there is isn't any resource management necessary. For the sake of example, let's say the `String` should be printed with a string prefix, too: the length of the prefix shouldn't be restricted, i.e., it won't fit into an `int`. Setting a prefix is already a bit more involved as a corresponding manipulator needs to be a class type:

```
class prefix {
    std::string value;
public:
    prefix(std::string value): value(value) {}
    std::string const& str() const { return this->value; }
    static void callback(std::ios_base::event ev, std::ios_base& s, int idx) {
        switch (ev) {
        case std::ios_base::erase_event: // clean up
            delete static_cast<std::string*>(s.pword(idx));
            s.pword(idx) = 0;
            break;
        case std::ios_base::copyfmt_event: // turn shallow copy into a deep copy!
            s.pword(idx) = new std::string(*static_cast<std::string*>(s.pword(idx)));
            break;
        default: // there is nothing to do on imbue_event
            break;
        }
    }
};
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, prefix const& p) {
    void*& pword(out.pword(stringFormatIndex()));
    if (pword) {
        *static_cast<std::string*>(pword) = p.str();
    }
    else {
        out.register_callback(&prefix::callback, stringFormatIndex());
        pword = new std::string(p.str());
    }
    return out;
}
```

To create a manipulator with argument an object is created which captures the `std::string` which is to be used as prefix and an "output operator" is implemented to actually set up the prefix in a `pword()`. Since there can only be a `void*` stored, it is necessary to allocate memory and maintain potentially existing memory: if there is already something stored it must be a `std::string` and it is changed to the new prefix. Otherwise, a callback is registered which is used to maintain the content of the `pword()` and once the callback is registered a new `std::string` is allocated and stored in the `pword()`.

The tricky business is the callback: it is called under three conditions:

1. When the stream `s` is destroyed or `s.copyfmt(other)` is called, each registered callback is called with `s` as the `std::ios_base&` argument and with the event `std::ios_base::erase_event`. The objective with this flag is to release any resources. To avoid accidental double release of the data, the `pword()` is set to `0` after the `std::string` is deleted.
2. When `s.copyfmt(other)` is called, the callbacks are called with the event `std::ios_base::copyfmt_event` *after* all callbacks and contents was copied. The `pword()` will just contain a shallow copy of the original, however, i.e., the callback needs to make a deep copy of the `pword()`. Since the callback was called with an `std::ios_base::erase_event` before there is no need to clean anything up (it would be overwritten at this point anyway).
3. After `s.imbue()` is called the callbacks are called with `std::ios_base::imbue_event`. The primary use of this call is to update `std::locale` specific values which may be cached for the stream. For the prefix maintenance these calls will be ignored.

The above code should be an outline describing how data can be associated with a stream. The approach allows storing arbitrary data and multiple independent data items. It is worth noting that `xalloc()` merely returns a sequence of unique integers. If there is a user of `iword()` or `pword()` which doesn't use `xalloc()` there is a chance that indices collide. Thus, it is important to use `xalloc()` to make different code play nicely together.

[Here](http://ideone.com/2T50aN) is a live example.

Comment: @0x499602D2: thanks! Trying to compile the code turned out to include a couple of additional errors which I are fixed now.

Comment: +1 A SSCCE (preferably as a live example) to see these dark but interesting corners of the library in action, would be much appreciated!